# RhinoMocks - when a method is called n times, how to test its parameters in the n - k call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have a method which calls another method exactly 4 times, each time with different parameters. I thought of writing 4 different unit test cases to check method is called with a specific value for each call.

Here is how my method looks:

```
public void MainMethod()
{
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = GetServiceProvider();

    string value1 = GetValueFromStorage("SomeArg1");
    // Call AnotherMethod
    serviceProvider.AnotherMethod(value1);

    string value2 = GetValueFromStorage("SomeArg2");
    // Call AnotherMethod
    serviceProvider.AnotherMethod(value2);

    string value3 = GetValueFromStorage("SomeArg3");
    // Call AnotherMethod
    serviceProvider.AnotherMethod(value3);

    string value4 = GetValueFromStorage("SomeArg4");
    // Call AnotherMethod
    serviceProvider.AnotherMethod(value4);
}
```

And here is my test method:

```
public void TestMainMethod()
{
    // Stub storage
    IDataStorage dataStorage = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDataStorage>();

    // Stub serviceProvider
    IServiceProvider dataStorage = 
         MockRepository.GenerateStub<IServiceProvider>();

    // stub for SomeArg1
    dataStorage.Stub(x => x.GetValueFromStorage(null)
                           .IgnoreArguments().Return("Value1"))
                           .Repeat.Once();

    // stub for SomeArg2
    dataStorage.Stub(x => x.GetValueFromStorage(null)
                           .IgnoreArguments().Return("Value2"))
                           .Repeat.Once();

    // stub for SomeArg3
    dataStorage.Stub(x => x.GetValueFromStorage(null).IgnoreArguments()
                           .Return("Value3")).Repeat.Once();

    // stub for SomeArg4
    dataStorage.Stub(x => x.GetValueFromStorage(null).IgnoreArguments()
                           .Return("Value4")).Repeat.Once();

   // call MainMethod
   MainMethod();

   // Assert that third call is called with "Value3"
   serviceProvider.AssertWasCalled(x => x.AnotherMethod("Value3"));
}
```

Here is seems that I can't ignore other calls and just verify that the third call is called with a specific  argument(or for that matter any other call in the sequence). It seems that I have to call the "AssertWasCalled" four times and  check individual argument in order. 
So how I can achieve this? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I realized that my code was not correct. I missed the Repeat.Once for the first call to dataStorage.Stub in the test, so it was always returning the Value1, so I thought I had to call AssertWasCalled for each call.

Comment: In your case `AssertWasCalled()` should work as expected. In more complex cases you can follow suggestion which @Marwijn provided in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(Action<T>)`. Long time since I've used it but it gives you a list with an array of objects which are the call parameters for each call made.

Answer (score 0):

If RhinoMocks supports something like Moq's Callback syntax, you could implement a Callback (or the equivalent) for IServiceProvider.AnotherMethod and have that callback put the parameter for AnotherMethod into a list for later inspection.  Something like this in Moq:

```
var anotherMethodParams = new List<string>();
var serviceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();

//Setup in Moq seems to be somewhat analogous to Stub in RhinoMocks
serviceProvider.Setup(sp => sp.AnotherMethod(It.IsAny<string>()))
               .Callback((string s) => { anotherMethodParams.Add(s); }));

var x = GetTheObjectThatWillCallServiceProviderAnotherMethod();
x.GetValueFromStorage("Value1");
x.GetValueFromStorage("Value2");
x.GetValueFromStorage("Value3");

//Assert that the parameter to the second call of AnotherMethod is as expected.
Assert.AreEqual("Value2", anotherMethodParams[1]);
```

Sorry for the Moq example, but that is what I am familiar with.

Comment: Rhino Mocks does indeed support something like this. Usually you use "Do" for this. See [here](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Mocks+The+Do()+Handler)